# Numerical Excel Value List in WorkFusion RPA Express

Tags: excel, workfusion

I’m currently in the process of developing a workflow in WorkFusion RPA Express.
I’m trying to copy list of numbers from an excel sheet to the clipboard and paste it in another excel sheet. The values copied are integers however when it’s pasted to the other sheet it pasted with the decimal point. How can I paste this as a string or as an integer?

[image: 1st image with the integer]

[image: The pasted values from the clipboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Number Format action (inside Variables group of actions) to reformat the value you paste in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of googling would have gone a long way here..

Select the cell(s) where you paste the data and adjust the number of decimals with these buttons. This will also automatically change the format from General/Text to Number

[image]